# I am trying to build custom List View

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to build custom List View that includes the following items on each row:

- clickable image
- text
- clickable image

I tried a lot of custom adapters that i found in other threads, but without any success until now. Both of the clickable images will use the text that is on that row.

Here is my row layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id`enter code here`="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Minus"
        android:src="@drawable/minus" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" >

</EditText>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Plus"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my current custom adapter:

```
package com.example.hrana.za.vkushti;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.ClipData.Item;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
super(context, textViewResourceId);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private List<Item> items;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {

super(context, resource, items);

this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = convertView;

if (v == null) {

    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.shoppingcart_row, null);

}

Item p = items.get(position);

if (p != null) {

    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);

    if (tt != null) {
        tt.setText(p.getText());
    }
}

return v;

}
}
```

And here is how i try call it in my main class:

```
List test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("test1");
    test.add("test2");
    test.add("test3");


    ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcart);

    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.shoppingcart_row, test);

    cart.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

When i try to open it, the application just crashes

Comment: Sorry. But I don't quite see the question.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "both images will use the text"? Also, what about your solution is _not_ working?

Comment: Could you please tell us, what is the problem with the implementation now. As you mentioned: "I tried a lot of custom adapters that i found in other threads, but without any success until *now*"

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: We are getting closer. What error are you getting in logcat and are you extending `ListActivity` in your calling `Activity`?

Comment: I am extending Activity:
    public class ShoppingCart extends Activity {


Regarding the error, there are multiple errors like every time when something go wrong, i don't know what to look for in this case

Comment: Then post your logcat but it looks like you are calling a `ListView` that you don't have in your xml so you are probably getting a `NPE` on `cart`

Comment: I think this is the error we are looking for:
    03-19 16:50:39.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hrana.za.vkushti/com.example.hrana.za.vkushti.ShoppingCart}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'


But i haven't used variable android.R.id.list anywhere in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `xml`

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
.../>
```

and extend `ListActivity`

or add a `ListView` in your xml with the name you are trying to access in

`ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcart);`

then you can extend `Activity`

**Edit**

If you use

`setContentView(R.layout.row); //row is the xml you posted above and put a ListView in`

then you can use the named `ListView` you have

otherwise, just `extend ListActivity` and use the `ListView` I gave above.

Comment: I added that. The activity now opens without any errors, but i got nothing on the screen..

Comment: I have list view listViewcart in my main xml since the begging here it is:

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewcart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        </ListView>

I think the application is looking for list view named "list" but i am using another one named "listViewcart"

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm a bit confused on exactly what you have now but try that

Comment: I just saw the edit. I am trying to do it with my named ListView and not to include the one called "list". Where exactly should i use the setcontentview?

Comment: In the `onCreate()` of your `Activity`

Comment: And in my case it should be: 
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart_row);

Right ?

Comment: Still looking for 'android.R.id.list' ...

Comment: Whatever the xml is that you have `ListView android:id=@+id/listViewcart...' You are getting the error again that you don't have a `ListView with android.R.list? You are extending `Activity`, correct?

Comment: No i was extending ListActivity. I just changed it to Activity and i got a: 

     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityomponentInfo{com.example.hrana.za.vkushti/com.example.hrana.za.vkushti.ShoppingCart}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: My answer explains the difference if you `extend Activity` or `ListActivity`. Where is the `NPE`?

Comment: The NPE is when trying to add the items i think. I just wrote a try catch block and i get 1 empty row on the page. We got some progress here!

Comment: The problem now is that i really don't know how to continue from here...

Comment: Woo hoo progress` :) Since we solved your initial problem and have changed the code, it may be best to accept this answer and post a new question with updated code and a clear question since this post is getting lengthy and you have a separate issue now. I'm not sure why you are using `List` and `ArrayList`. It may be better to use `ArrayList<String>` then step through and see what is `null` before posting a new question so you have a more precise question to ask. If you do this I will be happy to look at the new one. Hope this helps

Comment: Sounds good to me. I will re-check my program and made another thread if needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad we were able to get you going and thank you for showing appreciation for my time

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar where I created a custom view in XML layout file and then used a LayoutInflater to add to the ListView during runtime.  Then as you add the custom view to the ListView you change the values of the components of the view.

```
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llListing);
    View view = null;

// create new article_listing view                      
    view = (View)LayoutInflater.from(this.context).
    inflate(R.layout.article_listing, parent, false);

    // add title to title text in the newly added custom view
((TextView) ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3)).setText(sd.getArticleListing().get(l).getTitle());

    // add to parent LinearLayout
    this.parent.addView(view);
```

I apologize for formatting, still trying to figure out the code blocks in stackoverflow.

This is a simplified example of LayoutInflater.

So create a layout XML that represents the entirety of each entry into the list.  Then add each custom view into the list and modify the values.  Then add them to the parent view, your list.
I did mine with a linear layout and it works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

See https://github.com/cyrilmottier/ListViewTipsAndTricks

Create custom controllers, which doesn't inheritance parent view clicks. Like that:

```
public class DontPressWithParentButton extends Button {

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    // Make sure the parent is a View prior casting it to View
    if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}

}
```

Comment: How in the world can you answer a question which doesn't exist?